# Logica no SELECT, exibir um ou outro registro

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select, tabela-banco-de-dados

Preciso usar a regra que esta no if dentro de meu select.
Principal regra é caso tenha a compra e a compra tenha o status aprovado devo trazer o campo com a url do produto final caso não tenha devo trazer a url do produto amostra.

Principal regra:
Se tenho a compra feita e seu status é 1, trazer a trabalhos cientificos do tipo 2,

```
**TPTRABALHO.id_tipo_trabalho_cientificos = IF (COMPRAUSER.compra_user.status_compra_id_status_compra == 1 AND TRBCIEN.id_trabalhos_cientificos == COMPRAUSER.trabalhos_cientificos_id_trabalhos_cientificos) THEN 2 ELSE 1**
```

ou

```
**ARQTRBCINT.tipo_arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos_id_tipo_trabalho_cientificos = IF (COMPRAUSER.compra_user.status_compra_id_status_compra == 1 AND TRBCIEN.id_trabalhos_cientificos == COMPRAUSER.trabalhos_cientificos_id_trabalhos_cientificos) THEN 2 ELSE 1**
```

Segue alguns selects
    SELECT * FROM dbdevvendaassessoria.compra_user 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
    SELECT * FROM dbdevvendaassessoria.arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Meu select final

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbdevvendaassessoria.compra_user AS COMPRAUSER
INNER JOIN dbdevvendaassessoria.trabalhos_cientificos AS TRBCIEN
ON TRBCIEN.id_trabalhos_cientificos = COMPRAUSER.trabalhos_cientificos_id_trabalhos_cientificos

INNER JOIN dbdevvendaassessoria.autor AS AUT
ON TRBCIEN.user_system_web_id_user_system_web = AUT.id_autor

INNER JOIN dbdevvendaassessoria.especialidade AS ESPC
ON TRBCIEN.especialidade_id_especialidade = ESPC.id_especialidade

INNER JOIN dbdevvendaassessoria.arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos AS ARQTRBCINT
ON TRBCIEN.id_trabalhos_cientificos = ARQTRBCINT.trabalhos_cientificos_id_trabalhos_cientificos

INNER JOIN dbdevvendaassessoria.tipo_arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos AS TPTRABALHO
ON TPTRABALHO.id_tipo_trabalho_cientificos = ARQTRBCINT.tipo_arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos_id_tipo_trabalho_cientificos

INNER JOIN dbdevvendaassessoria.user_app AS USERAPP
ON COMPRAUSER.user_app__id = USERAPP._id

WHERE TPTRABALHO.id_tipo_trabalho_cientificos = IF (COMPRAUSER.compra_user.status_compra_id_status_compra == 1 AND TRBCIEN.id_trabalhos_cientificos == COMPRAUSER.trabalhos_cientificos_id_trabalhos_cientificos) THEN 2 ELSE 1
AND USERAPP.tokenuser = '158040683493255678149091'
AND TRBCIEN.id_trabalhos_cientificos = 6
```

Comment: Use o CASE  https://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/utilizando-select-case-com-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazendo alguns union etc e tals

Nao sei se é o correto...

MASSSSSS funcionou....

Cada **SELECT** faz um item da regra...

Segue....

```
"SELECT 
                                        tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos,
                                        tc.titulo,
                                        tc.subtitulo,
                                        tc.valor_trabalho,
                                        tc.capa_trabalho_cinetifico,
                                        esp.id_especialidade,
                                        esp.nome_especialidade,
                                        esp.descricao,
                                        aut.id_autor,
                                        aut.nome_autor,
                                        aut.nascimento_autor,
                                        aut.email_autor,
                                        aut.descricao_autor,
                                        aut.avatar_autor,
                                        atc.id_arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos,
                                        atc.url_tabalho,
                                        atc.data_inserido,
                                        cu.id_compra_user,
                                        cu.status_compra_id_status_compra
                                    from trabalhos_cientificos tc 
                                        left outer join compra_user cu
                                            on cu.trabalhos_cientificos_id_trabalhos_cientificos = tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos
                                        left outer JOIN user_app ua
                                            on cu.user_app__id = ua.`_id`
                                        left outer join arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos atc
                                            on tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos = atc.trabalhos_cientificos_id_trabalhos_cientificos
                                        inner join dbdevvendaassessoria.autor as aut
                                            on tc.user_system_web_id_user_system_web = aut.id_autor
                                        inner join dbdevvendaassessoria.especialidade as esp
                                            on tc.especialidade_id_especialidade = esp.id_especialidade
                                    where  atc.tipo_arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos_id_tipo_trabalho_cientificos = 1
                                    and cu.status_compra_id_status_compra <> 1
                                    and tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos = $idassessoria

                                    UNION
                                    SELECT 
                                        tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos,
                                        tc.titulo,
                                        tc.subtitulo,
                                        tc.valor_trabalho,
                                        tc.capa_trabalho_cinetifico,
                                        esp.id_especialidade,
                                        esp.nome_especialidade,
                                        esp.descricao,
                                        aut.id_autor,
                                        aut.nome_autor,
                                        aut.nascimento_autor,
                                        aut.email_autor,
                                        aut.descricao_autor,
                                        aut.avatar_autor,
                                        atc.id_arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos,
                                        atc.url_tabalho,
                                        atc.data_inserido,
                                        cu.id_compra_user,
                                        cu.status_compra_id_status_compra
                                    from trabalhos_cientificos tc 
                                        left outer join compra_user cu
                                            on cu.trabalhos_cientificos_id_trabalhos_cientificos = tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos
                                        left outer JOIN user_app ua
                                            on cu.user_app__id = ua.`_id`
                                        left outer join arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos atc
                                            on tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos = atc.trabalhos_cientificos_id_trabalhos_cientificos
                                        inner join dbdevvendaassessoria.autor as aut
                                            on tc.user_system_web_id_user_system_web = aut.id_autor
                                        inner join dbdevvendaassessoria.especialidade as esp
                                            on tc.especialidade_id_especialidade = esp.id_especialidade 
                                    where ua.tokenuser = '$tokenunser'
                                    and atc.tipo_arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos_id_tipo_trabalho_cientificos = 2
                                    and cu.status_compra_id_status_compra = 1
                                    and tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos = $idassessoria

                                    UNION
                                    SELECT 
                                        tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos,
                                        tc.titulo,
                                        tc.subtitulo,
                                        tc.valor_trabalho,
                                        tc.capa_trabalho_cinetifico,
                                        esp.id_especialidade,
                                        esp.nome_especialidade,
                                        esp.descricao,
                                        aut.id_autor,
                                        aut.nome_autor,
                                        aut.nascimento_autor,
                                        aut.email_autor,
                                        aut.descricao_autor,
                                        aut.avatar_autor,
                                        atc.id_arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos,
                                        atc.url_tabalho,
                                        atc.data_inserido,
                                        cu.id_compra_user,
                                        cu.status_compra_id_status_compra
                                    from trabalhos_cientificos tc 
                                        left outer join compra_user cu
                                            on cu.trabalhos_cientificos_id_trabalhos_cientificos = tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos
                                        left outer JOIN user_app ua
                                            on cu.user_app__id = ua.`_id`
                                        left outer join arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos atc
                                            on tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos = atc.trabalhos_cientificos_id_trabalhos_cientificos     
                                        inner join dbdevvendaassessoria.autor as aut
                                            on tc.user_system_web_id_user_system_web = aut.id_autor
                                        inner join dbdevvendaassessoria.especialidade as esp
                                            on tc.especialidade_id_especialidade = esp.id_especialidade 
                                    where atc.tipo_arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos_id_tipo_trabalho_cientificos = 1
                                    and tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos = $idassessoria

                                    and tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos 
                                    NOT IN (
                                    SELECT 
                                        tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos
                                    from trabalhos_cientificos tc 
                                        inner join compra_user cu
                                            on cu.trabalhos_cientificos_id_trabalhos_cientificos = tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos
                                        inner join user_app ua
                                            on cu.user_app__id = ua.`_id`
                                        inner join arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos atc
                                            on tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos = atc.trabalhos_cientificos_id_trabalhos_cientificos

                                        inner join dbdevvendaassessoria.autor as aut
                                            on tc.user_system_web_id_user_system_web = aut.id_autor
                                        inner join dbdevvendaassessoria.especialidade as esp
                                            on tc.especialidade_id_especialidade = esp.id_especialidade
                                    where atc.tipo_arquivos_trabalhos_cientificos_id_tipo_trabalho_cientificos = 1
                                    and tc.id_trabalhos_cientificos = $idassessoria);"
```